# MOS is on with no current

Tags: mosfet, analog

Here is a sentence from Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit that I don't quite understand:

"Note that in contrast to bipolar transistors, a MOS device may be even on if it carries no current."
Could you explain this?
Ron = Vds/Id
If there is no current then Ron is infinity.
How is it possible for the device to be on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a 10 ohm resistor then  measure it, it is 10 ohms. Now disconnect  it (no voltage or current applied) do you think it is still 10 ohms ? Or does it have an infinite resistance now that the current is zero ?

In the same way the channel in the MOSFET can be formed when Vgb (the channel is formed by the voltage between Gate and Bulk, the source or drain are not involved in this) is large enough. Then the conductive connection between drain and source is made even when the current is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain why we need Vbs is large enough here? How Vbs affect channel creation?

Comment: If you take an NMOS and you apply a positive voltage at the gate, this positive voltage attracts electrons from the substrate. These electrons gather just under the gate oxide. As the gate oxide is an isolator they cannot pass it. Here the electrons form a conductive channel. Also see http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/MOS_capacitor  and also have a look in your favourite textbook about the MOS transistor.

Comment: Hi, I understand this but why Vbs not Vgb that affect channel creation?

Comment: You're right it is Vgb ! Actually that was in my answer, someone changed it to Vgs and then I changed it back to Vbs. That was a type it should be Vgb ! You seeing the error means you understand it :-)